# US heat map error

Tags: r

I'm getting errors here:

```html
library(ggmap)    
library(maptools)    
library(maps)    
library(ggplot2)    
library(fiftystater)    
library(reshape2)    

data("fifty_states")

map_stats <- read.csv(file.choose())    
ggplot(map_stats, aes(fill = statename, map_id = state)) +    
  geom_map(map = fifty_states) +    
  expand_limits(x = fifty_states$long, y = fifty_states$lat) +    
  coord_map() +    
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",    
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

I'm basically following along with this example in this library: https://github.com/wmurphyrd/fiftystater

I'm trying to replicate this graph: https://i.imgur.com/DwIMgql.jpg
using this data set: https://i.imgur.com/Aj03Jrm.jpg (its all fifty states but you get the idea). 
Currently I'm getting a blank plot pane one of two errors:

**Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'state' not found**

or

**Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.**

**Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (54): fill, map_id**

Comment: Can you please post the data, either uploaded or using `dput` so we can avoid retyping the data? I think your problem is that `map_id` needs to be shared across both the `fiftystater` data and the plot data, as noted if you look at `?geom_map`. At least by default, the id for each state in `fiftystater::fifty_states` is not called `state` but `id`, and in your example picture it is called `statename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found i had to rename my `map_id = state` to the name of the state column in my table `map_id = statename` and it worked